# How to use Functions to create Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new to these prepared statements (all my code so far has been procedural), and I was trying to create a function for executing prepared statements so I could save time writing a statement for every SQL query I need.

```
function executeQuery($stmt,$mysqli,$sql,$type,$param1,$param2,$param3){
    $stmt = $mysqli -> stmt_init();
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($type,$param1,$param2,$param3);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

As you can see, my issue is that I would need a different function for prepared statements that only deal with 1 parameter in the query, one for 2 parameters, another for 3 and so on. I thought of making $param an array but I don't think that quite works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using arrays?

Comment: @MarcusAdams - I am not sure if that helps because in bind_param() it would require each variable listed by commas. If I make $param an array I get :
"Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables"

Comment: Use PDO instead of MySQLi...because it allows you to bind all your params from an array in the `execute()` method, which will make doing this 10,000 times easier. (I.e. an array can have variable length, variable number of params, so you don't need separate functions for each different number of params.)

Comment: @developerwjk is Mysqli completely incapable of binding arrays? Switching to PDO just for this seems excessive.

Comment: Mysqli is crappy anyway. First its too easy to confuse with mysql_. Second, it has OOP and Procedural methods which tends to sloppy code where people mix them. Third, PDO works for different databases (mysql, mssql, oracle) but MySQLi only works for MySQL. Etc. Its a good idea to switch to PDO.

Comment: Use PDO. With PDO, you don't have to bind them all in one statement. You can call bindParam multiple times.